# How do I stop .mdmp files from being created

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I have an instance of Solr, hosted with Tomcat that recently started creating minidump files. There are no errors in any of logs, and Solr continues to work with out a hitch.

The files are approximately 14gb, and are filling up the hard drive.  Is there a way to turn this off, while we investigate the issue?

Comment: I figured out how to fix this problem [see my question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769799/controlling-minidumps-in-java/22771547#22771547).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally speaking when JVM crashes the content of `hs_err` error log file  (controlled by `-XX:ErrorFile`) is often enough to point what the trouble may be.

To prevent Oracle JVM Hotspot to generate Windows minidump (mdmp files), the JVM option to use on command line is: `-XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash`

It exists since 2011 but was very difficult to find: [How to disable minidump (mdmp) files generation with Java Hotspot JVM on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769799/how-to-disable-minidump-mdmp-files-generation-with-java-hotspot-jvm-on-windows/22771547#22771547)

Answer (score 1):

This article has decent information on both Linux and Windows JVM dump files.  Have yet to test it myself on my current version of Java 7....

[From that site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/dumpfile.html):

**Disabling Text dump Files**

If you suspect problems with the creation of text dump files you can turn off the text dump file by using the option: -XXnoJrDump.

**Disabling the Binary Crash Files**

You can turn off the binary crash file by using the option: -XXdumpSize:none.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please avoid link-only based asnwers. Instead, try to provide an answer, based on what you saw on this site, as well.

Comment: Note that those options are for the JRockit JVM and not the standard Hotspot version

Comment: FYI: Here's a mapping table for JRockit JVM and HotSpot JVM options: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jrockit-hotspot/migration-guide/cloptions.htm -- Some of the dump options unfortunately only appear in the JRockit JVM column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 7? In that case revert to Java 5 or 6. Lucene/Solr and Java 7 don't go well together and it could be this creates the dump files. Otherwise if everything is working, just disable the dumping of files.

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to disable the dumps.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Might help if you told us what OS? Also try Googling. There are plenty of articles about disabling minidumps.

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008, but wouldn't disabling the dumps be a java option?  Good luck finding that article, I've been looking for days.

Comment: Check properties on My computer and then go to Advanced tab. Under startup and recovery there is an option to disable minidumps.

You never answered question whether you were using Java 7. Then you would have a cause as well.

Comment: That disables minidumps created by the OS, but not the one that JAVA creates.  I still never found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to disable the Java minidumps on windows. The strange part here is that everything on the server worked correctly, besides the hard drive filling up with minidumps.

We eventually re-installed everything, same version of Solr/Java/Tomcat onto a linux machine and didn't have the problem any more.  I would imagine that re-installing everything onto a windows machine would have also fixed the problem.  This was a strange one.

Comment: Inunno has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769799/controlling-minidumps-in-java/22771547#22771547) which works for me on Windows 7, using Java 1.7.0_13.