# How to disable minidump (mdmp) files generation with Java Hotspot JVM on Windows

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, jvm-hotspot

Currently I have a deployed executable jar file that creates large (7+ Gb) minidump files when it crashes. I would like to have a text representation of what caused the crash, not a binary file of the JVM state. I've tried using the information found in [this CodeRanch post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/604153/Tomcat/Disable-Minidumps-Java) and the documentation that I've found [in the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) doesn't seem to help.

I also referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162842/how-do-i-stop-mdmp-files-from-being-created) but there's no definitive answer.

Is there a typical way this is done that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Take care that `-XXdumpSize:none` is the JRockit specific option you may quickly find when googling about this question. Hotspot JVM is not JRockit.

Comment: FYI: Here's a mapping table for JRockit JVM and HotSpot JVM options: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jrockit-hotspot/migration-guide/cloptions.htm -- Some of the dump options unfortunately only appear in the JRockit JVM column.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a command line option that seems to do what I want. Launching the jar with

```
java -XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash -jar myJar.jar
```

Seems to do the trick and will generate error logs that are very small compared to the minidumps.

Comment: Really difficult to find this option to prevent generation of Java JVM mdmp files on Windows system.